# TAG And UpdateUI has private access in FragmentActivity Error For LoginActivity.java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Don't know why I am getting this error can anyone tell me that how to fix it.
this is login activity in java connected with firebase auth I am stuck in this before 3 days and still.

I pasted my code and also uploded my screen shot where you can see all the error.

Error where I always get on TAG and updateUI there two words always get error.

Download screen short of error message and code with error:

[image: Download Screen Short Of Error Message And Code With Having Error]

```js
package com.eassycars.www.licencespot;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class Activity_Login extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button singups,forgotpass,logins;


    RelativeLayout really1, really2;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            really1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            really2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Get Firebase auth instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity_Login.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity__login);


        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        singups = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singup);
        logins = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logins);
        forgotpass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forgotpass);


        singups.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Activity_Login.this, singup.class));
            }
        });

        forgotpass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Activity_Login.this, ForgotPassword.class));
            }
        });
        really1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rellayl);
        really2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.really2);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        logins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    updateUI(user);
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(Activity_Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    updateUI(null);

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone help fix this error because I am beginner and I don't have much knowledge so I am trying to get it.

Comment: you can add this line in your activity.  private static final String TAG = Activity_Login.class.getName();

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: Are you using firebase auth along with google?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because you are missing TAG and UpdateUI method in the class :

Please add the following `private static final String TAG = Activity_Login.class.getName();` as mentioned in the comment

Also, use the following method as you are using Firebase Auth

```
private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    hideProgressDialog();
    if (user != null) {
        mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.google_status_fmt, user.getEmail()));
        mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
        mDetailTextView.setText(null);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

After this you are good to go

Comment: Where Should I Have To Put updateUI code in my Activity_login means after which line

Comment: It's a method keep anywhere within the class, you can also keep it after onCreate Method

Answer (score 0):

You have to add TAG variable and updateUI method:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class Activity_Login extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "Activity_Login";
    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button singups,forgotpass,logins;


    RelativeLayout really1, really2;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            really1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            really2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Get Firebase auth instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity_Login.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity__login);


        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        singups = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singup);
        logins = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logins);
        forgotpass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forgotpass);


        singups.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Activity_Login.this, singup.class));
            }
        });

        forgotpass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Activity_Login.this, ForgotPassword.class));
            }
        });
        really1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rellayl);
        really2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.really2);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        logins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    updateUI(user);
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(Activity_Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    updateUI(null);

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        //implement your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: I Have Added this line in my activity login `private static final String TAG = Activity_Login.class.getName();` then the TAG error is fixed but still updateUI Error i am getting @udit

Comment: you need to add the updateUI function as well:

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        //implement your logic here
}